# Image View zoom in and out inside gallery view in android

Tags: android-widget

I'm developing one application for maintaining image like gallery application. Its working fine, but i need to implement zoom in and out effect for full size image view. In full size image view I'm using gallery view with in gallery view i have images it display one by one. i need to implement pinch zoom for visible image in gallery view.

I searched in net for long time but i got only image view pinch zoom if i will use that image view inside gallery view the gallery view on scroll method was hide only executed image view onScroll() and onFling() methods. so anyone have any idea share with me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I actually just ran into this and worked through it. (In my case) The gallery is grabbing the touch events after the very first touch (happening when the ImageView.onTouchEvent() returns false), which never allows the ImageView to handle these events after the very first one. This can be fixed by implementing three things.

First, in your zoom-able ImageView, ensure that onTouchEvent always returns true to indicate that it is handing touch events. This will make sure that the touch event is never sent to the gallery, allowing the second finger event and any movement to be handled by the ImageView.

Secondly, you will need to create some sort of flag in the ImageView indicating whether or not it is currently zoomed in.

Last, you need to capture the touch event manually in the Gallery, since it will never be passed up from the ImageView. This can be done by creating a custom class that extends Gallery, and overriding onInterceptTouchEvent(). This method captures the touch event when it is on its way to the child ImageView. Overriding this gives us a chance to allow BOTH the ImageView and the Gallery to handle the touch event. Below is the code that worked for me.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent( MotionEvent ev ) {

    View view = getSelectedView();
    CustomZoomImageView image = (CustomZoomImageView) view.findViewById( R.id.Image );

    if ( !image.isDraggable ) {

        onTouchEvent( ev );
    }

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent( ev );
}
```

The isDraggable variable is my indicator of whether or not the Image is zoomed in or not. If the image is not draggable, a.k.a. not zoomed in, then we also give the touch event to the Gallery for swipe detection.

Good luck!

Comment: Very Very Great answer by you sir. I appreciate your effort for this.